# google sheets horizontal alignment

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to change a cell format to horizontal alignment for the text. Can't get it to work. Here is my code so far.

```
data={
  "requests":[
  {
    "horizontalAlignment": {
        'range': {
            "sheetId": sheetId,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endRowIndex": 10,
            "startColumnIndex": 0,
            "endColumnIndex": 1
        },
        'Center'
    }
  }

  ]
}


result = g.service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=key, body=data).execute()
```

not sure how to specify the range in there with the horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script :

```
data={
  "requests": 
  [
    {
      "updateCells": 
      {
        "rows": 
        [
          {
            "values": 
            [
              {
                "userEnteredFormat": 
                {
                  "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "range": 
        {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 10,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
      }
    }
  ]
}

result = g.service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=key, body=data).execute()
```

#### Reference :

- [REST Resource: spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: that worked! but how did you know to use `updateCells`? i don't see it referenced on that page... also I see `rows` used in the pivotgroup only...

Comment: @jason I could know about this request body from [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest). From here, I clicked ``RowData`` of ``rows[]``, and clicked ``CellData``. Then from ``userEnteredFormat``, I could know ``CellFormat``.

Answer (score 0):

Use repeatCell to update at once.

```js
{
  repeatCell: {
    cell: {
      userEnteredFormat: {
        horizontalAlignment: "CENTER",
        verticalAlignment: "MIDDLE",
      }
    },
    range: {
      sheetId: 0,
      startRowIndex: 0,
      endRowIndex: 10,
      startColumnIndex: 0,
      endColumnIndex: 1,
    },
    fields: "userEnteredFormat"
  }
}
```