# Google Sheet API => Sheet creation OK but can't set specific defaultFormat

Tags: google-sheets-api

I succeeded to create a sheet, but horizontal and vertical alignments are set to defaults, not the ones I tried to set.
Here is the code

```
spreadsheet_body = {
    'properties': {
        'title': str("sme_"+jour_heure.read()),
        'defaultFormat': {       
            'horizontalAlignment': 'LEFT',
            'verticalAlignment': 'MIDDLE'
        }
    }        
}
print(spreadsheet_body)
# Création du fichier Google Sheet
request = service_sheet.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet_body)
response = request.execute()
print (response)
```

My sheet is correctly created by vertical and horizontal alignments are not set.

```
print (spreadsheet_body)
```

prints:

```
{'properties': {'title': 'sme_18_04_2020\n', 'defaultFormat': {'horizontalAlignment': 'LEFT', 'verticalAlignment': 'MIDDLE'}}}
```

but

```
print (response)
```

prints:

```
{'spreadsheetId': '1F2o5F8B-efoAOkg-d3z_2tGcPhvlp8gtcvGOGkGvAGI', 'properties': {'title': 'sme_18_04_2020\n', 'locale': 'en_US', 'autoRecalc': 'ON_CHANGE', 'timeZone': 'Etc/GMT', 'defaultFormat': {'backgroundColor': {'red': 1, 'green': 1, 'blue': 1}, 'padding': {'top': 2, 'right': 3, 'bottom': 2, 'left': 3}, 'verticalAlignment': 'BOTTOM', 'wrapStrategy': 'OVERFLOW_CELL', 'textFormat': {'foregroundColor': {}, 'fontFamily': 'arial,sans,sans-serif', 'fontSize': 10, 'bold': False, 'italic': False, 'strikethrough': Fal ./..
```

Title is OK but `verticalAlignment` is not ...

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [google sheets horizontal alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874219/google-sheets-horizontal-alignment). Also, the `defaultFormat` you use is a [read-only value](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SpreadsheetProperties)

Answer (score -2):

i believe you want to create new sheet with required alignment, with your code everything is a string like `"horizontalAlignment": "LEFT"` anything between "" is string and line ends with `;` instead of `,`

try this for creating new sheet and alignment

```
function alignment(){
//change sheet name as per your requirement
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet("yousheet");
var range = ss.getRange("A1:Z");
range.setHorizontalAlignment('left').setVerticalAlignment('middle');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but why couldn't i set those properties at creation ?

Comment: This is not correct. `spreadsheet_body` is a JSON and therefore the values are separated by commas, not semicolons. Also, the code the OP provided is for the Sheets API in Python, not Apps Script.